# Remove line from code

Tags: css

how i can remove line under Latest film and News if you look http://filmsground.net/

```
//Latest film start
function latestfilm ()
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmdb ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo '<h2> <div id="textbox">
            <p class="alignright"><span style="color:#3399ff"><a href="/?inav=news">News</a>&nbsp;<img title="New News corner" src="/img/new.png" style="height:15px; margin-bottom:-3px; margin-top:-3px; width:15px" />
            <p class="alignleft">Latest film added: <span style="color:#FFA500;">';
            echo '<a class="movie" href="?inav=movie&id='.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['title'].' ('.$fetch['year'].')';

            echo '</span><strong><div style="clear: both;"></div><hr class="bevel" /></div></div>';     


        }

}
//Latest film end
```

Comment: Hi, welcome here :) No, I am not looking at a third party website. Please show what the result is in your question, and show how the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<hr class="bevel">`
Your last echo should be `echo '</span><strong><div style="clear: both;"></div></div></div>';`

Comment: HR is needed and if i just add  your line still it has line space

Comment: Then add a border: none; style to the HR